# Formulas to populate spreadsheet with data

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, worksheet-function, array-formulas

I want to populate some cells given certain condition. The thing is, I have no idea how to do this with just formulas (can’t use macros or the sort).

Anyways, here’s my workbook, with its *****sheets*****:

```
**Sheet1**
TASK     Week
Test     1
Test2    1
Test3    1
Test4    2
Test5    3
Test6    2
Test7

**Sheet2**
Week
2

TASK
Test4
Test6
```

What I’ve been trying to do is:

- Populate Sheet2 tasks based on the week chosen.
- If I choose week #2 (in Sheet2), it should populate the task list (on the same sheet) with the tasks from Sheet1 that have that week number.

For example, right now it is (hypothetically) already loading tasks with a week == 2.

Any doubt, just let me know! I hope I made my issue clear.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I found a better solution.  This one requires an extra helper column on Sheet2, but it at least returns a compact list of matches (no weird spacing).

On Sheet2, in the first row of your list of matches (A3 in this example) enter the following:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$7,B3),"")
```

In the adjacent cell in the next column (B3 here) enter the following:

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(2,Sheet1!$B$1:$B$7,0),"")
```

where 2 is the week # you are matching.

In the next row enter the following formulas (in A4 and B4 respectively):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$7,SUM(B$3:B3),0),B4),"")
```

and

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(2,OFFSET(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$7,SUM(B$3:B3),0),0),"")
```

You can fill down this row of formulas as far as you like.

Comment: nice solution. Note that `IFERROR` (which is very useful) will work on Excel 2007 or higher.

Comment: More complicated than initially anticipated, but good nonetheless. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the first way to do this I thought of.  There are probably better, more elegant solutions, but I thought I'd share.

If you know the total number of tasks in your list on Sheet1, say *n*, you can do the following:

1. On Sheet 2 where you want your list of matching tasks, select from A4 (or whatever you want the top of your list to be) down to A(4+*n*-1).  So for your sample data, select A4:A10
2. Without changing the selection, type the following formula:

   `=IF(Sheet1!B2:B8=2,Sheet1!A2:A8,"")`

   where 2 is the week # you want to match.
3. Enter the formula by pressing Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

Comment: It works, but there is something else: it displays the value at the same row level like its original. I mean, if Test5 was in the fifth cell on Sheet1, this formula will make it display on the fifth cell of the destination range. Any idea how to change this? It should display them as the first values on Sheet2 (destination range). I suppose it’s because of the way your formula works (per cell).